# R box plot producing incorrect whiskers?

Tags: r, statistics

This is bound to be a misunderstanding on my part, but it looks like the R `boxplot` function is doing something odd with small datasets.

I have a vector of data that I designed to have two outliers (`-1`, `15`)

```
a <- c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,-1,15)
```

As I understand, the whiskers are supposed to be given by

> upper whisker = min(max(x), Q_3 + 1.5 * IQR)
>
> lower whisker = max(min(x), Q_1 – 1.5 * IQR)

I can calculate these quantities myself (for ease, `IQR = 2`, `Q1 = 4`, `Q3 = 6`) in `R` (I ignore the max/min as these whiskers are within the extremes of the data).

```
> quantile(a, 0.25) - (1.5*IQR(a))
25% 
  1 
> quantile(a, 0.75) + (1.5*IQR(a))
75% 
  9
```

Using `boxplot.stats` I expect the result to contain `stats`, which will have the values of the lower whisker in position 1 and the upper whisker in position 5. This is based on the help page for `boxplot.stats`:

> stats
>
> a vector of length 5, containing the extreme of the lower whisker, the lower ‘hinge’, the median, the > upper ‘hinge’ and the extreme of the upper whisker.

However, when I run `boxplot.stats` on `a` I get the values `4` and `6`.

```
> boxplot.stats(a)
$stats
[1] 4 4 5 6 6
```

I won't post the actual box plot here, but that also has the whiskers at `4` and `6` with the outliers at `-1` and `15` labelled.

Does anyone know why `4` and `6` are the whiskers for this box plot? Nothing in the documentation appears to cover a deviation from the relatively simple definition.

Comment: Whiskers are drawn at actual data values, not theoretical boundaries. It's more like upper_hinge = Q_3 + 1.5 * IQR and upper_whisker = max(x given x<=upper_hinge).

Comment: ["From above the upper quartile, a distance of 1.5 times the IQR is measured out and a whisker is drawn up to the largest observed point from the dataset that falls within this distance."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot)

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. I guess it's obvious when I think about it. I'm using these values to classify a new observation as being an outlier or not, hence the difference between the two methods is quite important.